# Execute php on a never-failing computer

Tags: php, refresh

This could be an easy question to many of you, I am sure...

My website has live content for users every friday afternoon. The info the users see (which is a SELECT from my database) refreshes every 10 seconds. My database is updated also every 10-30 seconds, through a php code that make some calculations.

The way I update my database is:

- I have a page called updatedb.php.
- I just visit www.mywebsite.com/updatedb.php
- This page refreshes every 10 seconds and every time it runs, it updates my database. Simple.

My problem:

What happens if I leave my computer alone and it loses the wifi connection? Or if it just has a failure? Or if there is a power outage? Then, updatedb.php does not refresh anymore, so my database stops updating.

What I look for:

Is there any other way to execute in a safe way updatedb.php? Even without turning on my computer? Of course I don't want the users to execute updateddb.php when visiting my site, as there are many users at the same time and they would all alter my database, which is a bad thing...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Search for cronjobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn cron jobs.

**Cron** is the name of program that enables unix users to execute commands or
scripts (groups of commands) automatically at a specified time/date.

[CRON Explanation](https://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

[More Details](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800)